# XML to SQL SERVER record insertion

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I having XMl file I am Reading All the Xml using this code . But mean while I want to insert XML records to sql table,Whatever I have Read.  I did not Find any Solution for that .XMl consists No of rows and how can i insert in Proper way .

```
       if (File.Exists(xmlpath))
          {
             try
              {
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlpath);
                var vrresult = from a in xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/Parts/Part")
                               select new
                               {
                                  S  = a.Element("Section").Value,
                                   M = a.Element("Mark").Value,
                                   Q = a.Element("Qty").Value,
                                   W = a.Element("Weight").Value,
                                   RD = a.Element("databaseUpdateMark").Value

                               };
                GridView1.DataSource = vrresult;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Lbmsg.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: I want to insert Records which i have read from xml to sql server table.

Comment: check the answer and dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if it works for you ...

Comment: hi check my edited answer link : http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2011/12/bulk-insertion-of-data-using-c.html to see hyow it wokrs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one example how to use OPENXML function

[Bulk Insertion of Data Using C# DataTable and SQL server OpenXML function](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2011/12/bulk-insertion-of-data-using-c.html)

---

Make use of function : [OPENXML (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx) which is avialble in sql server allows you to insert data in server....

also read : [Use OPENXML to insert values from a string of XML](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=499&lngWId=5)

**Example :**

```
--Use OPENXML to pull records from an XML string and insert them into a database

DECLARE @idoc int
DECLARE @doc varchar (1000)

--XML document

SET @doc ='
<ROOT>
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>Tom</FirstName>
        <LastName>Jones</LastName>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>Gus</FirstName>
        <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
    </Employee>
</ROOT>'

--Create an internal representation of the XML document
--the idoc variable is set as the document handler, so we can refer to it later

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc

-- Use the OPENXML rowset provider with an Insert
-- @idoc lets us know which internal representation of an xml doc to use
-- '/ROOT/Employee' shows us which node in the xml tree to work on
-- the 2 denotes we want to use elemenet centric mapping for the values, as oppsed to attributes or a combination of both
-- in the 'With' we specify how the output rowset will look

INSERT INTO Employees (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Employee',2) 
WITH (FirstName varchar(10),
LastName varchar(20)
)

-- Clear the XML document from memory

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Comment: Is there any other way .Just like reading from Can i read from vrresult Directly Each value . Or can you explain your solution .

Comment: @kuldeepverma - you need to create proceudre for this and have to pass the xml string to this and in code above xml string is replace by your parameter....I hope you understood....

Comment: Pranay Rana@ I am not understood this code . where and how can I call this stored procedure..Path is dynamic ..there are lot of xml files I want to insert as per user input

Comment: @kuldeepverma - call created oprocedure as you do in C#...that you can find by googing calling procedure from c# or .net ..